# CodeIgniter - 2 forms in a view

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a **view** which has 2 forms:

```
<table>
<th>Write a comment.</th>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),$form1); 
              echo form_textarea($comment);
              echo form_submit('submit','submit');
              echo form_close();
        ?>
    </td>
</tr> 


</table>

<table>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); 
                  echo form_dropdown('portion', $portion_options); 
                  echo form_submit('book','book');
                  echo form_close();
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the **controller** I check which button was clicked and then I perform some action by adding the corresponding form's values to the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['book']))
{
    //sending the data to the database
    echo "Book button clicked";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //sending the data to the database
   echo "Submit button clicked";
}
```

However when the 'book' button is clicked no action is performed. It is like the button was never clicked. Whereas when I click the 'submit' button, every action is done properly.

In the past I have used the same technique on plain php (i mean no framework, just php), and has worked fine for me. Does codeigniter need any further configuration? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And oh, tell me array in $form1. Where's it?

Comment: You should be able to have 2 forms on a page just fine. Can you post the uri_string that you're hitting in your browser and then post your entire method?

Comment: Can you also post the generated html for the forms?

Comment: I do have it on the top of my view. 

This is the array: 

$form1 = array(
 'name'   => 'form1',
 'id'  => 'form1'
);

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I was looking whether the problem is on the dropdown, and maybe it is there, since I changed the input from a dropdown to a text input and now the clicked button is beeing recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a hidden field to both forms called `form_id`with values 1 and 2 respectively? Easy to catch in your controller upon post; e.g.:

```
if($this->input->post()){
  switch($this->input->post('form_id')){
  case 1:
    // do stuff
  break;
  case 2:
    // do stuff
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried it your way, however, still just the 'submit' button is recognized

Comment: Are you using `if($this->input->post('book')) {`or raw `if(isset($_POST['book'])) {` ?

Comment: Actually I used the $this->input->post() since I thought that from the swich is going to be understood which form was posted. I tried now with $this->input->post('book') and still nothing.

Comment: I just tested locally, having `echo form_hidden('form_id', 1);` and `echo form_hidden('form_id', 2);` on both forms respectively. When in the controller I do `if($this->input->post()){
   echo $this->input->post('form_id');
  }` I get correct output - so it should work.

Comment: I think I figured it out. You're checking for `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` Since both buttons are `submit` buttons, your second `if`will always evaluate as true. So you need to check not for the existence of a `submit` but for the existence of another element, the hidden field as I suggested. Or, you could do this: `if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){ ` and `if($_POST['submit'] == 'book'){ `

Comment: Well I think my problem is at the dropdown. I changed the input from a dropdown to a text input and now the clicked button is beeing recognized! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),$form1);
```

and

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string());
```

Looks like you forgot to provide the settings in the second one like:

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),$form2);
```

Comment: no, either with <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); or <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),$form2);  does not work :/


$form1 = array(
 'name'   => 'form1',
 'id'  => 'form1'
);

and 

$form2 = array(
 'name'   => 'form2',
 'id'  => 'form2'
);

Comment: When I unite the forms to 1, then which button was clicked is recognized and work properly. However I need them to be on seperate forms if this is possible.

Comment: In any case do not use `if(isset($_POST['book']))` in CodeIgniter. Use built in `$this->input->post('book');`

Comment: And see in firebug/chrome developer tools what data is being sent to the controller, it can be seen in Network tab.

Comment: Even though I do not know how to use the firebug, in the Headers Tab at the Network tab I see that what I selected from the dropdown has been sent

Comment: I strongly recommend not using `$this->input->post('book')`.  It will break if you need to change to a `<button>` but you forget to provide a gratuitous `value=`.  I.e. it requires unnecessarily tight coupling between the controller and the view.  IMO isset() is better.  It's quite hard to realize exactly why someone's written the _correct_ alternative, which would be `$this->input->post('book') !== FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Well after spending my whole day on this I finaly managed to solve it somehow (although I believe it is not such a propper way to handle this).

Well:

```
$comment = array(
    'name'      => 'comment',
    'id'        => 'comment',
    'value'     => 'write you comment',
    'row'       => '5',
    'cols'      => '100'
    );

<table>
<th>Write a comment.</th>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); 
              echo form_hidden('form_id', 1);
              echo form_textarea($comment);
              echo form_submit('submit','submit');
              echo form_close();
        ?>
    </td>
</tr> 


</table> 

<table>
    <th>Write a comment.</th>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); 
                  echo form_hidden('form_id', 2);
                  echo form_dropdown('comment', $portion_options);
                  echo form_submit('book','book');
                  echo form_close();
            ?>

        </td>
    </tr> 


</table>
```

Probably the forms fields (textarea and dropdown) needed to have the same name (which i have set to 'comment'). Although I do not understand why :/

Thank you all for trying to help me :)